# Launch jobs in cache in a loop in bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop, caching

I try to launch multiple experiments, but I want to keep the code script in cache so that any change will not affect experiments waiting to be executed.

The bash script I use is:

```
for SIZE in 1 2 4 8 16; do
  python main.py $SIZE
done
```

The problem with my current script is that once I make changes to the code file `main.py`, the experiments waiting to be executed will use the modified `main.py`. For example, If `python main.py 1` is currently executed, any change to `main.py` will affect `main.py 2`, `main.py 4`... Is there a way to put `main.py`  in cache so that any change to `main.py` will not affect `python main.py $SIZE`?

Comment: Why does running `main.py` modify `main.py`? Is it a self-mutating virus? I'd try to not modify my code like that. But if you must, just copy the script before running, e.g., add a `cp main.py main-$SIZE.py` and then run that instead of plain `main.py`.

Comment: @Robert It's not changing itself, he's continuing to do development of it while running the script.

Comment: There's no way to do what you want automatically. The simple solution is to make a copy of `main.py` and run that, while you make changes to the original.

Comment: Computing 5 different sizes takes long time. I need to compare the performance of running these 5 different sizes with baselines. While I am waiting for the result, I plan to make some changes to the code and test the new implementation. The new modification might change many files in the project, so I cannot add copy to one single file (if I do so, I need to make copy to multiple files)

Comment: why not simply clone the code base for each set of experiments? if necessary use PYTHONPATH  to let versioned dependencies be found

Comment: You are right, I should clone each code base for each set of experiments, thank you  for the good suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do what you want is to read the code into a Bash variable and use the `-c` option to run it with Python.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

python_code=$(< main.py)

for size in 1 2 4 8 16; do
    python -c "$python_code" "$size"
done
```

- See the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) section of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for an explanation of `$(< main.py)`.
- This will not work if `main.py` contains binary data, particularly NUL characters (ASCII 0).  That is because Bash variables cannot hold NUL characters.
- I replaced the variable `SIZE` with `size` because ALL_UPPERCASE variable names are best avoided since there is a danger of clashes with the large number of special ALL_UPPERCASE variables that are used in shell programming. See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).
- See the [When Should You Quote?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F) section of [Quotes - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) for an explanation of why I used quotes on both of the variable expansions.  (The critical thing to know is that `$var` without quotes often does not expand to the string contained in the variable `var`.  `"$var"` always does.)

Comment: Thank you for the good suggestion! My project has multiple python code, say I make modification to `model.py`, this file will not be cached by using `python_code=$(< main.py)`, will it?

Comment: @CNDominic, correct.  This code will *only* cache the `main.py` code.  If files that are imported by `main.py` are changed between runs then the cached `main.py` code will import the updated files.  This goes beyond the scope of your question (which requires only a single file to be cached) so you may want to ask a new question.